# Displaying PySide2 UI from pyuic5 converted Python code

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside2

So I've designed my UI using QtDesigner and converted it into a Python Class, the class is named Ui_MainWindow and the function I want to call to display the UI is called setupUi.

I have found code snippets to display the UI using PySide1 but as a novice user I don't understand how to port the code to PySide2.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(381, 347)......................................etc.
```

https://pastebin.com/NJXEaLrF

I cannot find a full tutorial on converting the .UI file and how to use the output file.

Answer (score 3):

In the last version ( uic 5.15) the argument -x is no longer used you just use

```
pyside2-uic mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py
```

Use your transpiled file (`mainwindow.py`) within your main Python script:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow                                                                                                                  
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

MainWindow = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
```

Comment: The UI doesn't seem to be rendered with this code. Any idea why? With pyuic5 it does work.

Comment: @samwolfe Added usage directive.

Answer (score 1):

Sods law.. I spent days researching and found the answer minutes after posting. The trick is to use the -x parameter when using pyside2-uic and this will output extra code required to render the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after creating the user interface file mainwindow.ui in Qt Creator or Qt Designer you can convert it to Qt for Python (PySide2):

```
pyside2-uic -x mainwindow.ui -o desktop.py
```

If we use PyQt5 package we run pyuic5 for converting.
If we use PySide2 package we run pyside2-uic for converting.

Also you simply can load up the ui file using QUiLoader and QFile. Then use findChild method to extract the widget objects you need.

Comment: unknown option 'x'

Answer (score -1):

I used `pyside2-uic` to generate `.py` from `.ui`.
Adding this is what worked for me.
From: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
```